# Add page views in front page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I am making a blog-like site in drupal 7.15.

In the front page, I want to display the top 5 articles. I did this using a block type view.

At the end of this block, I also want to display a link called "All articles", which will lead to a page containing **all the articles**.

I have a made a **page type view** for this purpose, but I do not know **how to add the link to this view inside the block**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the view's edit screen for the Block display, go to the Pager section and click "No" next to where it says "More link:". In the dialog box that pops up, check the "Create more link" checkbox and save the view.

For this to work, you'll need to have the Page display in the same view as the Block one. So instead of creating a new view for the Page display as you did, create a Page display right in that same view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add HTML code in the as a Footer, as a Global Text Area, in the View and provide the link to anything you'd like in that Footer.

See this [Views tutorial video](http://vimeo.com/21052316).  At about 3:15 in the video, the instructor talks about adding a Views header which is very similar to Views footer.

Comment: I do not understand. I am new to drupal. Can you explain further?

Comment: @Shuaib I added a link to a video explanation in my answer.